# Vertically align contents of div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'd like to vertically align the contents of my `div`.

So basically 'Hello test' should be in the center of the `div`, vertically.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/z9zw0u9g/)

```css
.parent {
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    width:100%
}

.parent div {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div>
    <h1>hello!</h1>
    <p>test</p>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Flexbox solution](https://jsfiddle.net/z9zw0u9g/1/): `.parent { display: flex; align-items: center; }`.

Comment: @lmgonzalves That is excellent - please add as an answer :)

Comment: Done! But consider that `flexbox` is not supported in IE9- :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use table layout for this:

```css
.parent {
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}

.parent div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:50%;
}

h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div>
    <h1>hello!</h1>
    <p>test</p>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern `flexbox` solution (IE10+ and all modern browsers [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)):

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/z9zw0u9g/1/)

You can learn more about `flexbox` with [this excelent article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
body{
    margin:0 auto;
}
.parent {
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    width:100%
}

.parent div 
{
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```